# How to write a unittest for a sliding window?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Does Dataflow provide a way for me to set the start point of the first window? Or is there a formula for computing the start point?

I'm trying to write a unittest for a composite transform that is applying a SlidingWindow, a GroupByKey, and then a DoFn.

My windows will be

```
[To + i * period, To + i * period + duration)
```

where To is the start of the first window, period is the period of the windows and duration is the duration of the window.

So without knowing To I can't precompute the expected values in the output and pass them to DataflowAssert to validate the result.

Answer (score 1):

One work around would be to not use DataflowAssert. I could add two transforms to my test pipeline 1) one to attach the time window boundary to each data point and 2) one to write the data points to a temporary file.

After the pipeline runs, I can materialize the results by reading the temporary file. Since the data points are labeled with the end value of each window I can compute what the expected values should be.